# Make a Time.local object which incorporates a Date object in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Hi so in ruby im trying to make a program that takes an argument and returns the date exactly "x" number of months ago, I got it to say the year month and date but couldn't get it to display the hours minutes and seconds. any suggestions? Thanks

```
require "Time"
require "Date"
class "Time"
def months_ago(n)
y = Time.now.year
d = Time.now.day
mn = Time.now.month
s = Time.now.sec
h = Time.now.hour
m = Date.civil(y, mn, d)
m <<(n)
end
end
a = Time.new.months_ago(4)
puts a
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime:

```
require 'date'
puts DateTime.now << 4
```